# Get Nivo Slider Current slide title

Tags: wordpress, nivo-slider

Is there is a way to get current slide "title" of a Nivo Slider and display it in another div?

Answer (score 1):

Starting at line 209 in wp-nivo-slider.php

Change:

```
<div id="slider">
<?php 
            $category = get_option('wpns_category');
       $n_slices = get_option('wpns_slices');
?>
    <?php query_posts( 'cat='.$category.'&posts_per_page=$n_slices' ); if( have_posts() ) : while( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        </a>
        <?php endif ?>        <?php endwhile; endif;?>        <?php wp_reset_query();?>
    </div>
```

To:

```
<div id="slider" style="position:relative;">
query_posts( 'cat='.$category.'&posts_per_page=$n_slices' ); if( have_posts() ) : while( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
       <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            </a>
    <div id="slider-title" style="position:absolute; background-image:rgba(0, 0, 0, .5); color:#fff!important; top:10px; left:5px; display:block;"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
                <?php endif ?>
        <?php endwhile; endif;?>
            <?php wp_reset_query();?>
</div>
```

This will put the title in the upper left hand corner of the image with a semi-transparent background.